# How do I reduce mouse sensitivity in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Whenever I set my priority to high or above normal my mouse goes crazy. Every time I want to turn to the right or left a little bit with the mouse, it makes me do a 360. And when I try to engage in pvp, I always die because when they get behind me I spin in circles trying to simply face them.

This is really making me tired of Minecraft and I need a solution, fast! I haven't really tried finding a solution because none worked. I know its not my mouse because I tried the mouse on my friend's computer and it worked just fine.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about general computer tech support.

Comment: Set the priority of Java back to normal? This sounds like a "Doctor, it hurts when I stand on my head!" "Then I prescribe not doing that." kind of situation.

Comment: @BillyMailman I'm not entirely sure - but it seems like the issue is mouse sensitivity *in* minecraft - the first sentence about setting his 'priority to high' has me a little confused, however. Are you setting the process priority of java to high in the task manager (or Apple equivalent)?

Comment: @BillyMailman Actually, this is unusual. Setting Java priority above normal *shouldn't* affect mouse polling, but apparently Minecraft is doing something weird with mouse polling. That makes this Minecraft-specific tech support, and probably on topic.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce the issue. Check your sensitivity in the options menu, and make sure it is at 100% (the default value)

Answer (score 8):

This may not be to do with your sensitivity. I run Minecraft on a low-spec machine and also have this issue when I change priorities.

The issue here is that when you increase the priority of Java, you're making it higher priority than your mouse drivers. This means that when Minecraft is taking a large amount of processing power, the part of your computer which tracks your mouse is forced to wait- causing you to lose mouse control.

The obvious solution here is to not mess around with the priority settings and set Minecraft back to normal. If you have framerate issues, there are other solutions- I recommend Optifine. I recommend this, since screwing around with priorities can often have odd or unforeseen effects.

An alternative would be to find the process(es) related to your mouse drivers and ensure they are at equal or greater priority to Java's. This should stop the mouse issue.

Comment: Always nice to see an informative answer from experience! Have a +1, my good fellow.

Answer (score 5):

Unfortunately, I am completely unable to reproduce any potential issues caused by changing the priority of the `javaw.exe` process (which is the process controlling Minecraft).

However, there is a sensitivity slider in the options menu:

[image: The options menu; there is a sensitivity option.]

You can set your sensitivity anywhere from "*yawn*" to "HYPERSPEED!!!!" It is possible that your sensitivity setting was bumped up, which would cause the effect described.

Comment: Beaten by a minute! For fun I tried setting it to "HYPERSPEED!!!" in an attempt to replicate the problem, and found it to be decidedly not all that hyper.

Comment: @TrentHawkins Seeing "Trent Hawkins" and "Hyper" in the same post brings warm *pulses* to my memory :)

Answer (score 5):

I can't seem to reproduce your mouse turning issue. I set `javaw.exe`'s priority to 'high' and noticed no difference in mouse turning speed.

However, there are three possible solutions that I can think of off the top of my head that may resolve your problem:

1. Reduce mouse sensitivity in minecraft.

   - While in-game, hit escape to bring up the game menu and click on **Options...**
   - Drag the '**Sensitivity**' bar down, decreasing the percentage shown.
   - Play with sensitivity bar to find the sweet-spot where you turn at an acceptable speed, clicking '**Done**' and returning to the game to test various settings.
2. Change the operating system's pointer speed. (I'm only covering windows)

   - From the **Start Menu**, open up **Control Panel**.
   - Open '**Mouse**', and click on the '**Pointer Options**' tab.
   - Under 'motion', select your pointer speed, moving the bar more towards the word 'slow'.
   - Note that this will affect your entire operating system, and outside of the game you may need to increase the pointer speed back to what it was.
3. Don't "set the priority to high or above".

   - I don't know your system, or why you feel it is necessary to do this. But I, personally, have never had to and Minecraft runs fine. So if changing the priority causes these issues, don't?

Personally, I would play with Minecraft's sensitivity (#1) before changing the pointer speed (#2) of your entire operating system, but if setting the sensitivity in minecraft all the way down is not quite enough, it can work in conjunction with #2 to further reduce mouse movement.

Answer (score 2):

Same problem. I have the priority normal.

I have some solutions for you.

> 1. Update your mouse driver.
> 2. Reinstall Java. Reinstall Minecraft.
> 3. Reinstall your Operating System.
> 4. Buy an new mouse.(Just in emergency)
> 5. If you have the **priority** to normal. Set it ***lower***.